# Loading Serialised JSON Into Table?

Tags: json, swift, serialization, alamofire

Im having a really hard time wrapping my head around this process, I have made an API call and received back JSON, I then use a model to serialise the JSON so it can be used easily in my View Controller Table, but im having issues with how to call the API in the View Controller to have the result fit into my serialisation model. I hope I explained it correctly?

Here is the code of my API Request:

```
open class ApiService: NSObject {

    open func getData(completionHandler: @escaping (NSDictionary?, NSError?) -> Void) -> Self {

        let requestUrl = "https://wger.de/api/v2/exercise/?format=json"

        Alamofire.request(requestUrl, method: .get, encoding: URLEncoding.default)
            .responseJSON { response in
                switch response.result {
                case .success( let data):

                    completionHandler(data as? NSDictionary, nil)

                case .failure(let error):
                    print("Request failed with error: \(error)")
                    completionHandler(nil, error as NSError?)
                }
        }
        return self
    }
}
```

and here is the code of my serialisation

```
final public class Exercise: ResponseObjectSerializable {
    var id: Int!
    var description: String!
    var name: String!
    var muscles: String!
    var equipment: String!

    public init?(response: HTTPURLResponse, representation: Any) {

        guard
            let representation = representation as? [String: Any],
            let id = representation["id"] as? Int,
            let description = representation["description"] as? String,
            let name = representation["name"] as? String,
            let muscles = representation["muscles"] as? String,
            let equipment = representation["equipment"] as? String

        else { return nil }

        self.id = id
        self.description = description
        self.name = name
        self.muscles = muscles
        self.equipment = equipment

    }

}
```

But I cant work out how to fit this into my view controller function call which is currently this

```
    let apiService = ApiService()
let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)

var arrRes: [String] = []
var filtered: [String] = []
var searchActive: Bool = false

var id: Int?
var description: String?
var name: String?
var muscles: String?
var equipment: String?


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    exercisesTableView.delegate = self
    exercisesTableView.dataSource = self
    exerciseSearchBar.delegate = self
    getApiData()
}

func getApiData() {

    let _ = apiService.getData() {
        (data, error) in
        if let data = data {

            if let arr = data["results"] as? [String] {

                self.arrRes = arr
                self.exercisesTableView.reloadData()
            }

        } else if let error = error {
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The value for key `results` is `[[String:AnyObject]]` (an array of dictionaries) not `[String]`. Don't use `NSDictionary` in Swift, you throw away the important type information.

Comment: but then if i make it [[String:AnyObject]] rather than string, I cant process the data for example when using a  search bar as ill need to compare strings? Would I need to call as [[String:AnyObject]] and then convert into strings and int's using my serialisation?

Comment: If you don't cast to array of dictionaries you'll get nothing. You need to iterate thru the array to map the dictionaries to instances of your class. By the way, the object for key `muscles` in the JSON is also an array rather than a string.

Comment: thanks thats helpful, how could i go about doing this? as this is the one part im stumped on!

Comment: I wrote an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- First of all the HTTP response does not affect the custom class at all so I left it out.
- Second of all the values for keys `muscles` and `equipment` are arrays rather than strings.
- Third of all since the JSON data seems to be immutable declare the properties in the class as constant (`let`)

With a few slightly changes this is the custom class

```
final public class Exercise {
   let id : Int
   let description: String
   let name: String
   let muscles : [Int]
   let equipment : [Int]

   public init?(dictionary: [String: Any]) {

      guard
         let id = dictionary["id"] as? Int,
         let description = dictionary["description"] as? String,
         let name = dictionary["name"] as? String,
         let muscles = dictionary["muscles"] as? [Int],
         let equipment = dictionary["equipment"] as? [Int]

         else { return nil }

      self.id = id
      self.description = description
      self.name = name
      self.muscles = muscles
      self.equipment = equipment
   }
}
```

Then you have to declare the data source array

```
var exercises = [Exercise]()
```

And in the method `getApiData()` populate the array

```
     ...
     if let results = data["results"] as? [[String:Any]] {
        for result in results {
           if let exercise = Exercise(dictionary: result) {
              self.exercises.append(exercise)
           }
        }
        self.exercisesTableView.reloadData() // might be dispatched on the main thread.
     }
```

Note: `Any` is used in Swift 3, in Swift 2 replace all occurrences of `Any` with `AnyObject`

Comment: Thanks for this, trouble with the last part, when you let results = data, im getting use of unresolved identifier?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Alamofire, the code assumes that `data` contains the deserialized JSON. I was just replacing the original expression `if let arr = data["results"] as? [String] {} `

Comment: ive fixed it, im now getting Reference to property 'exercises' in closure requires explicit 'self.' to make capture semantics explicit, is it fine to add self.

Comment: Do what the compiler suggests and add `self`. I updated the answer

Comment: thanks, and has var exercises = [Exercise]()  replaced my old rrRes: [[String:AnyObject]] = [] variable? as i need to change the table loading code

Comment: Yes if you want to use the exercises array as the data source.

Comment: Thanks, and now ive changed the data type of the couse, im getitng an error here for my cellForRowAt function, what would be the correct statement after the changes? I edited arrRes to exercises.             if let row: NSDictionary = exercises[indexPath.row] as NSDictionary? {

Comment: `let row = exercises[indexPath.row]` (no type annotation, no `if-let`, no cast). The compiler infers that the type is `Exercise`. However I'd name the item exercise, not row: `let exercise = exercises[indexPath.row]`, `row` is associated with the row number.

Comment: Thanks ive implemented this but now its throwing Cannot subscript a value of type '[Exercise]' with an index of type '(Int, () -> _)'

Comment: The code is supposed to work, check your variable naming, avoid the name `row`, the type in the error message is a tuple Int and a closure. Edit the question and add the code for `cellForRow...` and `numbersOfRowInSection`.

Comment: i renamed to exercise as suggested code is:                 let exercise = exercises[indexPath.row] {
                    
                    guard let name = row["name"] as? String else {
                        print("Fail")
                        return cell
                    }
                    cell.textLabel?.text = name
                }
            }
            return cell

Comment: No, no, no. You do want to use the `Exercise` class, then use it. `name` is a non-optional **property**, forget the dictionary semantics : `let exercise = exercises[indexPath.row]` `cell.textLabel!.text = exercise.name`. The code will never  ***Fail***, forget `guard` and all type casts.

Comment: thats resolved it, apologies for my misunderstanding, the one last curious error is that Type 'ExerciseDatabaseController' does not conform to protocol 'UITableViewDataSource' but we are using the two mandatory functions of numberOfRowsInSection and cellForRowAt without errors

Comment: Press ⌘4 and open the disclosure triangle next to the error message to figure out which method is missing.

Comment: it was missing a brace which resolved it, it builds now and its showing data but only 4 entries of a larger JSON? any idea why its only listing a few? something to do with no refreshing or loading before its finished?

Comment: Change `muscles` and `equipment` to `[Int]`, if there are values in the array they are integers. Please read the JSON.